# Find sub collection not adjacent but in the same order in java

Tags: java, search, collections

How can I find in Java (8) if a collection (list or set) is subset of another collection although the elements are no adjacent for example [1,2,3,4,5] as the large collection and if I want to search for [2,3,4] return true, also [2,5] return true BUT [4,2] return false although 4 and 2 are in the collection but are not in the same order

Is there a utility help me to do this?
Or a piece of code doing this properly?

Thanks

Comment: What do you think about `[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]`. It contains `[3,4,2]` in order, so is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns true if a contains b.

This function converts collection to array, if your collection class not implements `.toArray()` function it won't work!

```
public class CollectionUtils {
    private CollectionUtils() {
    }

    /**
     * @return true if A contains B in order
     */
    public static <T> boolean checkAcontainsB(Collection<T> a, Collection<T> b) {
        if (a == null || b == null || b.size()>a.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (b.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        final Object[] aElements = a.toArray();
        final Object[] bElements = b.toArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++) {

            int bIndex = 0;
            for(int j = i; j< aElements.length; j++) {
                if(aElements[j] == bElements[bIndex]) {
                    bIndex++;
                    if(bIndex>=bElements.length) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

you can test it:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Assert.assertFalse(CollectionUtils.contains(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4), Arrays.asList(2,3,4,5)));
    Assert.assertTrue(CollectionUtils.contains(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4), Arrays.asList(2,3,4)));
    Assert.assertTrue(CollectionUtils.contains(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4), Arrays.asList(2,4)));
    Assert.assertTrue(CollectionUtils.contains(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), Arrays.asList(3,4,2)));
    Assert.assertFalse(CollectionUtils.contains(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4), Arrays.asList(2,3,4,5,6)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not fully tested, but you can try something like this,

```
    int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] y = {2,5};
    int yIndex = 0;

    for(int i: x){
        if(y[yIndex] == i){
            yIndex++;
            if(yIndex >= y.length){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(yIndex == y.length ? "Match" : "Not Match");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use one utility method provided by Collections that does exactly what you intend to do.

```
    Collections.disjoint(c1, c2)
```

The above method returns true if the two collection passed does not have any item in common and the other way around. Exactly the thing you want.

Comment: Isn't this the thing you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any generic solution for your problem, but below you could find an custom-made solution for your problem.

```
public static boolean containsArray(int[] a, int[] s) {
    if (a == null || s == null) return false;
    if (a.length < s.length) return false;

    int i = -1;
    for (int current : s) {
        do {
            i++;
            if (i == a.length) {
                return false;
            }
        } while (a[i] != current);
    }

    return true;
}
```